# Search Bar disappears in scrolling, how to prevent this action

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

My search bar seems to disappear on scrolling, even if i were use

```
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false
```

Also using below

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

has no effect

Seems to have no effect, my code for search controller addition is

```
searchControlInstance = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
      
        searchControlInstance.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchControlInstance.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
       
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        searchControlInstance.searchBar.returnKeyType = .done
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

I do have

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

but turning it to false seems to have no effect the search bar just disappears like in picture, where am i making the mistake, can any one suggest, i do not use storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set it in this way:

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchControlInstance
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

Comment: yup .. you need to set both :)

Comment: I get the same result , i have mentioned this in my answer, thanks

Comment: any other settings where i need to add some thing ?

Comment: Hum, I was thinking you didn’t tried both together.

Comment: hey it worked i needed to disable navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true, thanks